# Error with date using gtrendsR

Tags: r, gtrendsr

Why the code below works just fine:

```
library(gtrendsR)

ch <- gconnect("usr@gmail.com", "psw")

query1 <- gtrends(query = c("Ludwig von Mises", "John Maynard Keynes", "Karl Marx"),
                 geo = c("BR"),
                 start_date = "2016-01-01",
                 end_date = "2016-03-31")
```

But if I change the date to:

```
query2 <- gtrends(query = c("Ludwig von Mises", "John Maynard Keynes", "Karl Marx"),
                 geo = c("BR"),
                 start_date = "2010-01-01",
                 end_date = "2016-03-31")
```

R trows an error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Works here, I got `packageVersion("gtrendsR")`=  ‘1.3.3’

Comment: Had to do `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en", TZ = 'GMT') ` for it to work. My default time zone is `"BRT"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I live in Brazil. The package seems not to handle the time-zone correctly if I do:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en", TZ = 'GMT')
```

before i run the code, it works.

If I enter the debug the problem is on the function

```
.processResults(resultsText, queryparams)
```

on the line

```
weeks <- lapply(weeks, as.POSIXct, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

if I change to

```
weeks <- lapply(weeks, as.POSIXct, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, tz = 'GMT')
```

it also works.